# Using SVG images in Xamarin.Forms Tab.Icon

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

Today I started with `Xamarin.Forms` and immediately I stumbled upon a problem.
I am using the ***Xamarin.Forms Shell*** project template and I want to change the Icons inside `AppShell.xaml` TabBar to SVG icons.

I have added my SVG images into a new Folder 'Resources' in the Shared project (NETSTANDARD2).
When reading about using SVG icons in `Xamarin.Forms` I stumbled upon the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) NuGet package and followed the following tutorial: https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/29/sharing-svg-icons-across-platforms-in-xamarin-forms/

However, after setting everything up, I noticed I cant set a SVG using this library on a TabBar --> Tab.Icon, it generates the following error:

```
The type 'ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built
```

Code:

```
<!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar>

    <Tab Title="Home">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="home.svg" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

After some more reading I stumbled upon a few posts where people had the similar issue, and seemingly this is still not fixed: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1297

My question
is, is there any other way to get the SVG image inside the Tab.Icon property (with or without the `FFImageLoading` library)?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason I have edited the post

Comment: You can set it in custom renderer for tabbedPage. Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179773/how-to-use-svg-image-for-tabbed-page-tabbar-icon